# Can't show component as placeholder in react-lazyload

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I'm making a netflix clone. I'm fetching and displaying data from the TMDB API. Now, I'd like to show a skeleton component while the images are being rendered. Ideally, that would look something like this:

[image]

I'm using the react-lazyload package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazyload) to lazy load the images. The problem is, it doesn't display the skeleton component as the placeholder, while the images are being rendered. This is what I'm currently getting:

[image]

The code:

```
return (
            <div className="row">
                <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
                <div className="row_posters">
                    {this.state.movies && this.state.movies.map(movie => (
                        <LazyLoad key={movie.id} className="poster_container" placeholder={<SkeletonPoster key={movie.id}/>} offset={200}>
                            <img
                                key={movie.id}
                                className="poster" 
                                src={`${this.baseUrl}${movie.poster_path}`}     
                                alt={movie.name}
                            />
                        </LazyLoad>
                    ))}
                </div>

            </div>
        )
```

How do I get the skeleton component to be shown while the image renders?

Comment: Are you missing a closing tag in ?
placeholder={<SkeletonPoster key={movie.id}/>} offset={200}> }

Comment: Nope, the closing tag for placeholder is already there.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am currently fighting with the same problem

Comment: Nope, didn't find anything

Comment: Facing the same problem.

Comment: Why not try using the loading attribute in the img tag and set it to lazy (instead of using a package)? I'm not sure if you'll be able to show the placeholder while the image is loading, but it's worth a try.